# Why will the colour of the active link not highlight blue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a navbar so that when you are on the page lets say "Home" - the link of "home" on the navbar highlights blue therefore when you are on a different page it is no longer blue. I am doing this in a ruby on rails app so I need to use javascript in order for this to happen. Below is the HTML for the navbar as well as the javascript that I am trying to use.

Navbar HTML

```
<div class="navbar-box d-flex">
  <div class="logo-box"></div>
  <div class="links d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
    <a><%= link_to "HOME", root_path %></a>
    <a><%= link_to "ABOUT US", about_path %></a>
    <a><%= link_to "APARTMENTS", index_path %></a>
    <a><%= link_to "CONTACT US", new_contact_path %></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const currentLocation = window.location.href
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const menuLength = menuItem.length;
for(let i = 0; i < menuLength; i++){
  if(menuItem[i].href === currentLocation){
    menuItem[i].className = "active"
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.active{
  color: #7587bf

}
```

Comment: Try calling `console.log(currentLocation)` and `console.log(menuItem[i].href)` and see how they differ.

Comment: I don't use Ruby on Rails, but I just searched for some examples, and it doesn't seem like `link_to` should be nested inside `<a>`. It expands to `<a>` by itself.

Comment: I'm sorry question was closed, it's not a duplicate of the question cited. There are other ways to implement what the OP has asked, besides pulling the href attribute from the <a> tag. For example it's possible to do this in Rails, without any javascript. But since the question has been closed, I cannot offer this suggestion!